# How to limit the risks of mutability in this example?

Tags: kotlin, immutability

My code is something that is similar to:

```kotlin
fun verify(problem,answer){
    val errors: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    if (!condiditon_1) {
        errors.add("Condition_1 is not verified")
    }
    if (!condition_2) {
        errors.add("Condition_2 is not verified")
    }
    return errors
}
```

Here `errors` is a mutable list. I am trying to rewrite the program limiting the mutability

**The first way is:**

```kotlin
errorsImmutable = errors.toList()
```

and return the immutable list `errorsImmutable` to prevent modifying it from the exterior.

**Another solution is:**

```kotlin
fun verify(problem,answer){
    val errors: List<String> = emptyList()
    if (!condiditon_1) {
        val mutableList =  errorLogs.toMutableList()
        mutableList.add("Condition_1 is not verified")
        errors = mutableList.toList()
    }
    if (!condition_2) {
        val mutableList =  errorLogs.toMutableList()
        mutableList.add("Condition_2 is not verified")
        errors = mutableList.toList()
    }
    return errors
}
```

Which one is better. More generally, is there an even better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you can create a collection already populated, that tends to be better than creating an empty one and then populating it — for a variety of reasons, including immutability as you say.  It's not always possible (or elegant), of course, but in this case here's one way:

```
fun verify() = listOfNotNull(
    if (condition1) "Condition1 is not verified" else null,
    if (condition2) "Condition2 is not verified" else null,
)
```

or the equivalent:

```
fun verify() = listOfNotNull(
    "Condition1 is not verified".takeIf{ condition1 },
    "Condition2 is not verified".takeIf{ condition2 },
)
```

That way you never see a mutable reference to the list (though one may be involved inside the `listOfNotNull()` implementation).  And because the list is now a single expression, you can use an expression-body function, and let it infer the type.  (Shorter code isn't *always* simpler or clearer or more maintainable, of course, but here I think it might be — depending on the surrounding code, of course.  Either way, it's often a useful learning exercise.)

And here's a more declarative approach, which defines the conditions separately (and factors out the common message format):

```
val conditions = listOf(
    Pair({ condition1 }, "Condition1"),
    Pair({ condition2 }, "Condition2"),
)

fun verify() = conditions.filter{ it.first() }
                         .map{ "${it.second} is not verified" }
```

PS. I missed another tweak: it might be slightly more readable if you use [`to`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html) instead of specifying `Pair` explicitly:

```
val conditions = listOf(
    { condition1 } to "Condition1",
    { condition2 } to "Condition2",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You neglected to show the return type of the function in the example. It is generally considered fine to simply return a read-only List and trust that consumers will not cast it to a MutableList to modify it.

```
fun verify(): List<String> {
    val errors: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    if (!condiditon_1) {
        errors.add("Condition_1 is not verified")
    }
    if (!condition_2) {
        errors.add("Condition_2 is not verified")
    }
    return errors
}
```

There isn't a clean way to create a truly immutable List without writing your own List class that is immutable. Note that the standard library's `listOf` function returns read-only lists, not immutable lists, with the exception of the overload that has a single element argument.